# Whitney umbrella birational to $\mathbb{A}^2$ but not isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, affine-geometry

Define the Whitney umbrella as the affine surface $V(z^2 - yx^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^3$. I've come across an exercise that asks me to show that this surface is birational, but not isomorphic, to $\mathbb{A}^2$.

My intuition is that this follows from the fact that the Whitney umbrella is self-intersecting. Am I headed in the right direction?

Edit: I thought I had a rational parametrization to start things off, but it doesn't actually seem to work. It was $\mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^3 : (a, b) \mapsto (ab, b, a^2)$.

Comment: Your parametrization doesn't land into the Whitney umbrella.

Comment: Your intuition is correct.  The Whitney umbrella is singular, so can't be isomorphic to to $\mathbb{A}^2$

Comment: How 'bout $(a,b)\mapsto (a,b^2,ab)$?

Comment: Excellent, @Ted!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I had to delve into my memory, but I used this parametrization about 30 years ago to compute some singular Chern class integrals for the umbrella. :)

Answer (score 3):

a) Since the umbrella $U= V(z^2 - yx^2)$ is singular (along all points of its stick $V(x,z)$)  it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb A^2$, since  $\mathbb A^2$ is nonsingular.

b) The umbrella $U$  is however  birational to $\mathbb A^2$ because $$\mathbb A^2\setminus V(u) \stackrel {\cong}{\to} U\setminus V(x,z):(u,v)\mapsto (u,v^2/u^2,v)$$ is an isomorphism between an open dense set of $\mathbb A^2$ and an open dense set of $U$.
[The inverse isomorphism being $ U\setminus V(x,z)\to\mathbb A^2\setminus V(u): (x,y,z)\mapsto (x,z)$]

Comment: I'm trying to make sure that I understand the idea, but I'm not familiar with the notation $V(u)$. Do you just mean the zero locus of $u$?

Comment: Dear user97901, yes exactly: $V(u)$ is the set of points $(u,v)\in \mathbb A^2$ with $u=0$. In other words $V(u)=\{0\}\times \mathbb A^1$, the $v$-axis.